# Projective duality vs. Fourier transform of IC sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

*Disclaimer:* I am far from expert in the topics under discussion.

Let $A \subseteq V$ be a closed affine cone in a vector space, defined by polynomial equations.

In classical "projective duality", one takes the conormal bundle to $A_{reg}$ (the smooth points) inside $T^* V \cong V\times V^*$, takes the closure, and projects to $V^*$ to get the "projectively dual cone" $A' \subseteq V^*$. The same construction applied to $A'$ gives $A$ back.

Alternatively, one can start with the constant sheaf on $A_{reg}$, take its perverse extension on $V$, then the Fourier transform of that on $V^*$ (again an IC sheaf), and finally take the support of that.

> Must the support of that Fourier transform be $A'$?

For the answer to be "no", the following must happen, as I understand it.
The characteristic cycle of the perverse extension may be reducible (which is sad but at least to some extent understood; in particular in work of Tom Braden). One component $CA$ of it will be the closure of the conormal bundle, but there may be others, say $B$. But then we project to $V^*$, 
and find out that $\pi(B) \supset \pi(CA)$.

Tag as appropriate.